# Client certificate authentication on certain requests

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, https

Following [this question](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/234055/how-to-design-a-single-request-non-ca-based-custom-server-to-server-authenticat) and the answers I got, I've decided to follow the route of client certificates. However, I actually need to enforce security only on certain requests, and [Microsoft's documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/certauth?view=aspnetcore-3.1) confirms that this can't be expected of plain SSL authentication.

Here's what I need:

- my server (ASP.NET Core) exposes HTTP endpoints;
- some of those are public and can be used by anyone, some are private;
- only a closed list of known clients is allowed to use the private endpoints.

Is there a way to request client certificates from clients, but to also

- ignore them if the request is for a public endpoint
- check that the certificate is in a list if the request is for a private endpoint?

Comment: Can't the two be managed as separate apps?

Comment: How are your services hosted? IIS?

Comment: @Ramesh In theory yes, but the application si in production already, the two halves are intertwined and share a common code base, and it would be quite some work to separate them. Not that it cannot be done, but I'm trying to find out if it's possible to keep them together.

Comment: @JohnWu Yes, IIS with AspNetCoreModule and AspNetCoreModule2 (there are several applications like this, some .NET Core 2.1, some 2.2 and some 3.1).

Comment: You may try setting client certificate to accept instead of required and control authorization based on path. Hope https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/certauth?view=aspnetcore-3.1 this helps

Comment: @Ramesh I totally overlooked that. I'll look into it, thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

You may set the client certificate to accept in SSL Settings of IIS

[image: IIS Screenshot -> SSL Settings -> Client Certificates]

Accept will take a certificate if it's presented, but will also continue with connections where the client doesn't present one.

You may use the current authentication and authorization to check if the user is mapped to the current request to proceed with private API